# CSS animation restarted on HTML injection

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I'm applying CSS animations to the content of a page. The animations are loaded dynamically and there I have a behavior I don't understand : I play the first animation and it works fine. Then I add and play the second animation and then the first animation is played again, together with the second animation. How can I get rid of this ?

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
function addFadeOut() {  
  container.innerHTML += "<div id=\"be\" style=\"position:absolute;z-index:2;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: green;animation: fadeOut 3s forwards;\" />"
}
function addFadeIn() {
  container.innerHTML += "<div id=\"bb\" style=\"position:absolute;z-index:1;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: red;animation: fadeIn 3s forwards;\" />"
}
setTimeout(addFadeOut, 4000);
addFadeIn();
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try by adding animations separately ?

Comment: They are already added separately no ? Or I don't understand what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `innerHTML +=`, use `appendChild()` with actual DOM-Nodes. Maybe like the following:

```
//a simple Utility to convert html into a documentFragment (can contain multiple DOM-nodes)
var dummy = document.createElement('div');
function fromHTML(html){
    var node, frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(dummy.innerHTML = html; node = dummy.firstChild; frag.appendChild(node));
    return frag;
}
```

and your adapted code

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
function addFadeOut() {  
    var markup = "<div id=\"be\" style=\"position:absolute;z-index:2;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: green;animation: fadeOut 3s forwards;\" />";

    container.appendChild(fromHTML(markup));
}
function addFadeIn() {
    var markup = "<div id=\"bb\" style=\"position:absolute;z-index:1;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: red;animation: fadeIn 3s forwards;\" />";

    container.appendChild(fromHTML(markup));
}
setTimeout(addFadeOut, 4000);
addFadeIn();
```

the reason for this reset is that

```
container.innerHTML += markup;
```

is the same as

```
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + markup;
```

wich is also the same as

```
var newMarkup = container.innerHTML + markup;
container.innerHTML = newMarkup;
```

and now you should see, that by assigning a new value to `innerHTML` the node first throws every current childNode away, and created new ones from the passed `newMarkup`. To you, the former and the new node look the same, to JS they are not. they may be equal, but not identical. Therefore: new node, new animation.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works with only small adaptations of the original code. Just one question to be sure, why did you put the dummy variable outside the fromHTML function ?

Comment: @user2223898 To not create a new `dummy` for each call of `fromHTML` but instead only once and then reuse this object. This node is used to parse the passed Markup, it is not the node that get's added.

Answer (score 1):

CSS animations trigger on an element whenever it is inserted in the DOM.

The first item (with the `fadeIn` animation) is re-created when you use `innerHTML` again 4 seconds later (which means that the previous DOM element representing that div is removed, and another identical element is inserted).

If, as Thomas says, you insert the elements with explicit DOM manipulation, you can avoid that:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
function addFadeOut() {
  var el = document.createElement("div")
  el.style="position:absolute;z-index:2;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: green;animation: fadeOut 3s forwards;"
  container.appendChild(el)
}
function addFadeIn() {
  var el = document.createElement("div")
  el.style="position:absolute;z-index:1;opacity:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: red;animation: fadeIn 3s forwards;"
  container.appendChild(el)
}
setTimeout(addFadeOut, 4000);
addFadeIn();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sure your solution works, but I have approved Thomas solution because it needs less changes in the original code.